# Google maps stays on top left hand corner

Tags: html, css, google-maps, position

I want to position Google maps on the bottom of my page, but no matter what numbers I insert, it keeps staying on the top left hand corner and won't budge. I can resize it, but I can't seem to move the positioning. Any help?

HTML:

```
<iframe 
    marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="422" height="300"
    frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
    src="https://maps.google.ca/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;cid=7805933538308657347&amp;q=Hibiscus&amp;gl=CA&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed">
    </iframe>
```

CSS:

```
    .iframe  {
    position: absolute; 
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 8000px;
    left: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the iframe in the footer tag of your page.

HTML

```
<html>

<body>
stuff...
</body>
<footer>
<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;"
    marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="422" height="300"
    frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
    src="https://maps.google.ca/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;cid=7805933538308657347&amp;q=Hibiscus&amp;gl=CA&amp;hl=en&amp;t=m&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed">
    </iframe>
</footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.iframe  {
position: absolute;
padding-bottom: 65%; //65% padding-bottom is massive... are you sure you want that much?
padding-top: 30px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
//overflow:hidden; Why that? Doesn't do anything usefull in this situation.
//left:400; Is it supposed to be 400px? If so, your page is pretty huge considering you have a map the size of your page.
}
```

Comment: I've tried the footer tag and it doesn't seem to work. I fixed the 400px, padding, and overflow however. I had the map the width as my text blocks, which is why it is 400px.

Comment: Is there any other CSS that modify your iFrame? Because when I'm testing this on w3school "Try it" it works perfectly. Are you using a master page? Make sure the footer tag is unique on the page. Right click your page and check source code to see.

Comment: I'm using one master external css page, and nothing else is part of the iframe except for the ones I stated above. It works on w3school and jfiddle yet I still don't understand why it stays on the top.

Comment: what I meant by master page is if you have a master page over your html page. if so, check if there is already a footer in it. Else, try putting the iframe at the end of all your elements on your page or inside a div tag. If this still doesn't work, try using google chrome developper kit (inspect element in chrome) on your page and search from there. It's the best way to find and fix problem. Alternatively you can post your page HTML in your question and I might be able to help you further or find what bugs it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing position absolute, I guess you can just add `bottom:0;` in the iframe class if you want it to be always at the bottom of the page

```
.iframe  {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 400px; <-- do you want to set margin on the left side of the map?
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your CSS. You have a `.iframe` which means any elements with `class="iframe"` will inherit those properties. Your html you supplied doesn't look like it has anywhere a class of iframe. You can either keep your CSS the same and add `class="iframe"` to your iframe or change `.iframe` to `iframe` in your CSS. Personally I'd go with the `.iframe` and add `class="iframe"` to the `iframe` but I'd rename the class to something like `.google-maps`

```
<iframe class="iframe" ...></iframe>

iframe /*or*/ .iframe{
    position: absolute; 
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 8000px;
    left: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Looking over your question again I have a suggestion to try position:{absolute, relative or fixed} to see if changing the position attribute which might solve your problem.